# Neural network's weights optimization using a genetic algorithm

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I am currently developing a video game with some friends of mine, for a course we have in AI.

We all have different constraints ; our is to use Neural Networks to define the behavior of the AI. This part is in Python.

Basically, our game is like [Towerfall](http://www.towerfall-game.com/), but much simpler. The map is static, the player has 5 lives, either the AI. You can move left, right, jump and click to shoot a bullet at cursor's position. So it is a battle to death.

Initially, we thought about using genetic algorithm to train our network. We defined a topology and whatever it is, we planned to optimize the weights using GA's.

The plan would be to generate populations, testing NNs directly within our game, gathering the results (fitness?) and generating a new population using the ranking of the previous ones.

But we do not really know how to implement this, or either if it is possible or if it would give good results.

Should we use a weighted average of weights during reproduction ? How to apply "mutations" ? What structure should we use to represent our NNs ?

If you have any clue or advice..!

Thanks a lot !

Comment: This is an extremely vague/opinion based question that I've flagged for closure. But to point you in a path you can continue to google - genetic algorithms require you to have some representation of a gene that you can mutate, which also expresses to the data-structure you need. For example, you could use a list of floats as the "gene" and convert that into the weights for the nodes. How you do the mutation, how often etc. is all something you need to determine. Importantly - a small mutation in the gene should only make a small change in the behaviour (in general at least).

Comment: @Jul_DW ANN training is time consuming. If you want to have an efficient computer opponent think about other A.I. options.

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a complete tutorial about optimizing artificial neural networks using genetic algorithm with Python implementation. It is titled "**Artificial Neural Networks Optimization using Genetic Algorithm with Python**" It is available here at [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/artificial-neural-networks-optimization-using-genetic-ahmed-gad), [KDnuggets](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/03/artificial-neural-networks-optimization-genetic-algorithm-python.html), and [TowardsDataScience](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-reduction-using-genetic-algorithm-with-python-403a5f4ef0c1).

You can read more and more in my 2018 book that covers GA in one of its chapters. The book is cited as “**Ahmed Fawzy Gad ‘Practical Computer Vision Applications Using Deep Learning with CNNs’. Dec. 2018, Apress, 978–1–4842–4167–7**” which is available here at [Springer](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781484241660). Also here at [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484241665).